# Steps for proving proposition given the conditions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

When a question asks you to give an example in the domain of real numbers where

$\forall x$, $\forall y$, $\exists z$ P(x, y, z) is true,

but $\forall x$,  $\exists y$, $\forall z$ P(x, y, z) is false

How would I prove that my example will satisfy both these statements? Or what should I already know or apply in this question to prove it? 
Whenever I get a question prove the statement, I get a brain fart and don't what to write.

Comment: I would play around with less than and greater than relations in P. Thinking about the difference between for any number there exists a number greater than it, but there does not exist a number greater than ALL numbers.

Comment: What is your example?  You do not prove both statements.  You prove and disprove the other.